# Alias for $last in nested ng-repeat always returns true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two nested ng-repeat and need to rename $last for something like outerLast and innerLast. I'm doint it using ng-init="outerLast= $last" and ng-init="innerLast= $last", but it's not working. Both variables are always true. I guess it's cause $last will change from true to false in the last child scope create by the previous iteration as soon as the new iteration creates a new child scope and probably ng-init is not creating a bind between the new variable and $last.

How can I implement the expected behavior for outerLast and innerLast variables?

Comment: could you provide some code? I think this has to do with the following: ng-repeat will always iterate through all items and also the last and therefore it will be always true.

Comment: Did you find an answer @diego-margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the nested loop, use `$parent` to access the outer scope. So to access the `$last` variable, you must use `$parent.$last`.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps you visualize how to reference $parent.last

```
<div ng-repeat="items in GroupOfItems">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    outerLAST: {{$parent.$last}}
    innerLAST: {{$last}}
  </div>
</div>
```